# Words Growth in Finite Groups

Tags: gr.group-theory, graph-theory, finite-groups, geometric-group-theory

Let $G$ be a finite group with a set of generators and let $\Gamma$ be its Cayley Graph. Let $b_k$ be the number of elements in the ball of radius $k$. I am interested in what is known about the sequence $(b_k)$. (Of course its length is the diameter of the graph.)

This is not an area I know much about and I am not completely sure what I am looking for. I will appreciate any suggestion where to start. (Of course a lot is known for infinite groups)

Comment: This is of course very highly dependent on the generating set since if you take all elements as generators the diameter is 1.

Comment: Yes, of course. Eventually, I'll be interested in a family of groups with given generators and in the asymptotic behaviour.

Comment: There are many "expansion" results. See e.g. *E. Breuillard, B. Green, T. Tao: Approximate subgroups of linear groups, Geom. Funct. Anal. 21 (2011), no. 4, 774-819.*  and *L Pyber, E. Szabó: Growth in finite simple groups of Lie type, J. Amer. Math. Soc. 29 (2016), no. 1, 95-146.*

Comment: @Ycor thanks. Do you know if any of them deals specifically with this sequence? Or are they more "general"?

Comment: I think this question needs to be made more specific, otherwise, you're almost asking to describe a whole research area.

Comment: @verret I am not sure. I think that there is a lot of research on growth in general in finite groups and it is clearly related. However, I am not sure how much this sequence was studied.

Comment: Could you please clarify if you ask either for  

- concrete results for a specific group, e.g. Rubik's cube group with generators as in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimal_solutions_for_Rubik%27s_Cube

- or asymptotic results for an infinite series of finite groups, e.g.$\mbox{GL}_n(p)$  with $p$ fixed,  $n \rightarrow \infty$ ?

Proofs for concrete groups can be complicated, as the Rubik's cube example shows. For asymptotic results you may neglect low-order terms in the same way as you do this in complexity theory, but you must specify the infinite sequence you are interested in.

Comment: @MartinSeysen I am interested in asymptotic results for a family of groups and probably at what you suggested to neglect, namely the beginning of the sequence. So how does the beginning of the sequence relates to the structure of a group? But as I said I do not have a specific question.

Comment: I don't claim to be expert on this subject, but asymptotic results make sense only for an infinite family of groups $G^i$ (with certain generating sets) and corresponding sequences $(b^i)_k$. All I want to say is that asymptotic bounds for $(b^i)_k$ - if you find any - will usually depend on two variables, namely the  radius $k$ and a parameter $i$, where $i$ somehow describes the 'size' of the group $G^i$. Here you may use the language of complexity theory (e.g. big-$O$ notation, ignoring lower-order terms) for describing asymptotic results, once you have found them.

Comment: @YiftachBarnea these papers deal with arbitrary subsets. Typical expansion results take the form: if $S\subset G$, either $|SS|\ge\min(c|S|,|G|)$ for some $c=c_G>1$.

Comment: @Ycor thanks, this is helpful. So what I would really need to understand is the dependents of $c$ in $G$ and also can I get it to be bigger if I take $|S|$ to be relatively small.